Limit of a real numbers sequence
If we consider sequence $a$ where every $a_n$ is a rational number, then we can have a sequence, where:

Every $a_n$ is a rational number
Limit of $a$ as $n \to\infty$ exists
Limit of $a$ is not a rational number

A good example of that could be some "infinite fraction tower", like $1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+...}}$ with its limit being $\phi$.
My question is - could the same happen to a sequence of real numbers?
My best shot was with something like $1-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-...}}$, which if "solved naively" would result in a complex number as a limit. However the problem is that such a sequence isn't even well-defined: it depends on how we "cut off" the fraction and could even result in division by 0 at which point all bets are off.
So, could we have a sequence $b$, such that every $b_n$ is a real number, its limit as $n \to\infty$ exists but it's not a real number?

This is just the completeness property of $\mathbb{R}$ and is certainly a duplicate.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers

@YvesDaoust fair point! However, I didn't consider that for the reason that if we are to have a sequence of natural numbers with a finite limit, then such sequence must "terminate" at some point (i.e. all members after some finite index should be exactly the same) - which is why I thought it's not the same case, since every member of it is forced to belong to the same set in order for the limit to exist in the first place.

No we cannot. For $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$. However $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and its closure is equal to $\mathbb{R}$ itself.

Thanks! I am not a professional mathematician and only do math "for fun" (as in, thinking about stuff on my own), so I often miss the "right term" to search for - in this case, "closed set" (I think). I tried searching for "limit of the real numbers sequence" etc - yet that didn't lead to anything relevant; so it seems I ended up asking something really trivial.

Here's another way to see why we can't have a sequence of real numbers converging to a non-real complex number.
So take any $z=a+bi\in\mathbb C$ with $b\neq0$. Then, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have that
$$\lvert z-x\rvert^2=\lvert (a-x)+ib\rvert^2=(a-x)^2+b^2\geq b^2.$$
In particular the distance from $z$ to any real number is always at least $\lvert b\rvert>0$, so can never get arbitrarily close to $z$ by real numbers.
